# PHP check for email, telephone, and name in mysql database

Tags: php, mysqli

i have a current database called "call_list", inside of that there's a table called "call_list" with the colums id, name, email, and tel.

for some reason, my code isn't acting right, it keeps inserting the same info even if it matches something in the database.

db.php

```
<?php
//server info
$servername = "***.***.**.***";
$username = "********";
$password = "*****************";
$dbname = "call_list";
//create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
//test connection
if(!$conn){
    die("Connection Failed: ". $mysqli_connect_error());
}
//check for name in the database
$sql_check = "SELECT * FROM call_list WHERE name = '".$name."'";
$sure_check = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_check);
$checked = mysqli_affected_rows($sure_check);
if($checked == 0){
    //check for email in database
    $sql_check2 = "SELECT * FROM call_list WHERE email = '".$email."'";
    $sure_check2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_check2);
    $checked2 = mysqli_affected_rows($sure_check2);
    if($checked == 0){
        //check for telephone in the database
        $sql_check3 = "SELECT * FROM call_list WHERE tel ='".$tel2."'";
        $sure_check3 = mysqli_query($sql_check3);
        $checked3 = mysqli_affected_rows($sure_check3);
        if($checked3 == 0){
            //try to insert info
            $sql2 = "INSERT INTO call_list (name, email, tel) VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$tel2')";
            if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql2)){
            //set session variable to success
            $_SESSION['result_sql'] = "<div class='alert alert-success'>New record created successfully</div>";
            }else{
                //set session variable to failure
                $_SESSION['result_sql'] = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Error: ". $sql . "<br>". mysqli_error($conn)."</div>";
            }
        }else{
        //set session variable to duplicate telly
        $_SESSION['result_sql'] = "<div class='alert alert-warning'>Client phone number already in database</div>";
        }
    }else{
    //set session variable to duplicate email
    $_SESSION['result_sql'] = "<div class='alert alert-warning'>Client email already in database</div>";
    }
}else{
//set session variable to duplicate name
$_SESSION['result_sql'] = "<div class='alert alert-warning'>Client name already in database</div>"; 
}
//finally close the connection.
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: 1st: where does $name, $email, ... come from? 2nd: learn about prepared statements, your vulnerable to sql-injections.

Comment: and you could of course reduce all the ifs to only one if you'd use `Select * from call_list where x=y OR z=a...`

Comment: 3rd mysqli_affected_rows takes a mysqli  link object, not a mysqli_result object as it's parameter: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php

Comment: all the variables are from contact.php(takes $_POST Info and mails it)which is working correctly, this code is a php file thats included/required into contact.php.  this is why i ask questions. i know my code is inferior. i also can't gain knowledge from reading manuals.. and the php.net examples aren't helping me any. i apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I refactored your code to make it simpler, easier to read and therefor to *DEBUG*.
I guess your main misstake was passing a result instead of a `link` object to `mysqli_affected_rows($link)`:

```
 $sure_check3 = mysqli_query($sql_check3);
 $checked3 = mysqli_affected_rows($sure_check3);
```

See the [documentation here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php).

This should be a working code:
(Note, that I've changed to [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)!)

```
<?php
// assuming we have a valid mysqli-connection as $conn
// assuming we have escaped user-input in $name, $email, $tel

// 1. check if we have an entry in database that matches any user-input
$sql_check = "SELECT * FROM call_list WHERE name = ? OR email=? OR tel=? ";

$stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql_check);
if(!$stmt) {
    echo "DB-Error: prepare failed";
    exit;
}

$bindSuccess = mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sss", $name, $email, $tel);
if(!$stmt) {
    echo "DB-Error: bind param failed";
    exit;
}
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $savedName, $savedEmail, $savedTel);
$flagOneFound=false;
// check what had matched to set flags, that we then can return fitting messages later
while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
    $flagOneFound=true;
    if($savedEmail===$email) {
        $flagEmail=true;    // you also could echo out here and exit script - maybe better
    }
    if($savedName===$name) {
        $flagName=true;     // and/or here
    }
    if($savedTel===$tel) {
        $flagTel=true;      // and/or here
    }
}

if(!$flagOneFound){
    // insert info
    $sql_insert = "INSERT INTO call_list (name, email, tel) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql_insert);
    // I left out all the checks here for simplicity
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sss", $name, $email, $tel);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    if(mysqli_affected_rows($conn)===1) {   // note, that I pass $conn here! not $stmt
        echo "Insert successfull";
    }else{
        echo "could not insert new user",
    }
} else {
    if($flagEmail) { echo "There's already a record with that Email" };
    if($flagName) { echo "There's already a record with that Name" };
    if($flagTel) { echo "There's already a record with that Tel" };
}

?>
```